# How to use expansion files with react native?

Tags: android, react-native

i'm developing an offline app, that app has around 600+ images & videos. Apk file size is ~450MB. Google Play limits upload up to 200MB, only option is to use apk expension files.

How to use that with react-native ?

How use expansion files with react native ??

Comment: Are you using png/jpg? Try to use svg as it will reduce the size.